FFmpeg hardware encoding and/or decoding when using v360 and crop filters?
I'm using ffmpeg to dewarp a fisheye camera. It works great but is doing 100% of the work on the CPU.
ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner \
  -v error \
  -allowed_media_types video \
  -fflags nobuffer \
  -flags low_delay \
  -timeout 5000000 \
  -user_agent go2rtc/ffmpeg \
  -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp \
  -i my_camera_stream \
  -vf v360=fisheye:output=dfisheye:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90,crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:in_h/2 \
  -c:v libx264 \
  -g 50 \
  -profile:v high \
  -level:v 4.1 \
  -preset:v superfast \
  -tune:v zerolatency \
  -pix_fmt:v yuv420p \
  -an \
  -user_agent ffmpeg/go2rtc \
  -rtsp_transport tcp \
  -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/my_hash

I'm trying to see if any of the decode / encode work can be offloaded to hardware via vaapi but not having much luck.
My attempt at enabling hwaccel is failing
ffmpeg \
  -hide_banner \
  -v error \
  -allowed_media_types video \
  -fflags nobuffer \
  -flags low_delay \
  -timeout 5000000 \
  -threads 2 \
  -hwaccel vaapi \
  -hwaccel_flags allow_profile_mismatch \
  -hwaccel_device /dev/dri/renderD128 \
  -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
  -rtsp_flags prefer_tcp \
  -i rtsps://my_camera_stream \
  -vf v360=fisheye:output=dfisheye:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90,crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:in_h/2:,scale_vaapi=in_w:in_h \
  -c:v h264_vaapi \
  -g 50 \
  -profile:v high \
  -level:v 4.1 \
  -preset:v superfast \
  -tune:v zerolatency \
  -pix_fmt:v yuv420p \
  -an \
  -user_agent ffmpeg/go2rtc \
  -rtsp_transport tcp \
  -f rtsp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/my_hash

With an error stating:
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_crop_1' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0


Is it even possible to make use of vaapi hardware support anywhere in the ffmpeg pipeline when using v360 and crop filters?
If so what am I doing wrong.


Try adding hwdownload before using "CPU filters" (after GPU decoding), and hwupload before using GPU accelerated filters and GPU encoding. You may also have to use format filter after hwdownload. Try: hwdownload,format=nv12,v360=fisheye:output=dfisheye:ih_fov=180:iv_fov=180:pitch=90,crop=in_w:in_h/2:0:in_h/2,hwupload,scale_vaapi=in_w:in_h. Note that I don't think that it is going to work at first try (your command is just too complicated...).
